# Can't access wp-admin after migrating website to Chinese server

Tags: database, wordpress, authentication, migration, wp-admin

Hello I'm having some issues with accessing my wp-admin after migrating a website onto a Chinese server.

I used WP Migrate DB plugin to ensure all mentions of my old domain was replaced with the new domain.
I deactivated plugins, changed the theme, created a new admin user, checked user roles and a few other possible solutions that I can't recall at this time.
Looking for general ideas on how to resolve this that I might not have tried.

Thanks

Comment: Is any error showing? or password not matching?

Comment: No error shows, just a page with this text: "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." and the passwords match.

I have searched for solutions but none of them have been successful so far.

Comment: Try by resetting .htaacess file.

Comment: I tried resetting the .htaccess but it hasn't worked.

Comment: What does the `home_url` and `site_url` show in `wp_options` table?

Comment: The siteurl and home are both the correct domain

Comment: Two possible reasons then, 1) Using a version of PHP that’s incompatible with the version of WordPress you have installed often creates this error. Upgrading your version of PHP can often resolve this issue. 2) you are blocked by a security firewall, You may need to contact hosting support.

Comment: Just a quick update on this question. I found a user meta key baIN6_capabilities but the installation is looking for bain6_capabilities. Due to this issue, the user capabilities was returning null, which was preventing me from accessing the wp-admin.

So the issue was a multi-case prefix where Wordpress was only looking for lowercase prefix data.
Thanks for your advice